# Resolve npm dependencies from workspace in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, npm, visual-studio-code

I come from Java world and I'm used to code with Maven and Eclipse, which makes very easy to work with local dependencies as the IDE + M2Eclipse plugin is able to [resolve dependencies from the workspace](https://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/dependencies.html).

Now that I'm developing in JavaScript with NPM and VS Code, I find that you have to use manual options such as `npm link + npm build --watch` or `npm pack + npm install <path>` to work with local dependencies.

I'm developing an Angular application which codebase is split in different Git projects and npm packages, so we waste a lot of time testing local dependencies and also it is error prone.

I guess that this is caused by the different nature of JavaScript and Npm but, is there any plugin or option to ease local depevelopment in VS Code?

EDIT: I have seen [this article about Yarn Workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2017/08/02/introducing-workspaces/) and it looks like what I'm looking for... anything similar in npm? I see Lerna is an option but only for monorepos, I have separated Git repos for each library.

EDIT2: To clarify the problem, lets say I'm developing two Angular libraries, each on a different Angular workspace. Library A depends on library B. I use VS Code workspace to have these two Angular workspaces open at the same time and edit them together. If I change library B I have to build it and link it so that I can test the changes locally in library A before publishing. This is what "resolve dependencies from the workspace" solves in Eclipse + M2Eclipse in Java, the IDE just builds and links projects together. Thats what I'm looking for in VS Code + NPM in Angular.

EDIT3: New [workspaces feature in NPM 7](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces) looks promising, I will give it a try. Any thoughts about it?

Comment: You are not clear on what the actually problem is here, what errors? and why do you think time is wasted? You are trying to solve an unknown problem with a feature of a different packaging system that is more file system based (remote or local) where as npm is more service based.

Comment: When you say "local" dependencies you mean dependencies on your own libraries? If so you don't even need to use npm if you don't want to, though npm does make it easier to ensure all developers install the same dependencies the same way

Comment: Please see EDIT2 with clarifications.